# How do i configure route 53 to work with naked and www domains using ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-route53, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm finding a bunch of mixed information on how to do this and its confusing, can someone help me understand the proper way to configure a node/express/mongo app using aws?

My current setup is running through ELB. When I tried to link up a domain I've purchased on name cheap I did the following according to the manual.

1. Create a zone ( I used my naked domain example.com )
2. Redirect DNS to the zone DNS
3. Configure an Alias to point to the NS

This was pretty straight forward but I noticed that my naked domain worked but the www.example.com didn't work. So I thought it would be simple enough to create another alias but no luck.

It looks like I can create another zone for the www.example.com domain but It seems that might not be the right way to do it, and would bring the cost up.

So my questions laid out

1. Should I be using ELB for this?
2. Should I be using route 53?
3. If so what steps can I take to get my domain working as expected with and without the www ?

Comment: You definitely don't need to create another zone just for a subdomain. It sounds like you are doing the correct thing, pointing www to the ELB alias, like you did for the naked domain record. It could be that your web server is not configured properly to respond to both the naked domain and www. Can you see in the server logs if the requests are getting to the server?

Comment: Hey @MarkB, thanks you! I didn't have to change anything, after viewing the logs I did see the request coming through which confirmed it was set up correctly. Something but of been working itself out because now I can hit www and the naked domain as expected.

Comment: You probably just needed to wait a bit for the new domain record to propagate. When you create a new record you generally need to wait at least a few hours for it to propagate.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works as expected if you setup a www alias that points to the NS record. It just might take a few extra minutes to catch up some times especially if you just started pointing the domain to the new NS server.

@MarkB suggested to check logs in order to confirm traffic is hitting the server, in my case it started working right after I did that.